# Restrict ng-href by validation in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've been searching around for a solution on this one and have been stumped.  I'm kind of new to AngularJS so I don't know all of the good tricks it's got yet.  I have a multi-part form that is **HTTP GET**ed at the end using **ng-href**.  Here's the code snippet that submits everything.

`<a ng-href="#/report/{{ctrl.model}}" ng-click="ctrl.createReport()">Finish</a>`

now I'm faced with adding validations to this form, and I want to prevent the link from being followed if the validation fails.  Validation logic is contained in a controller function, the function will return true or false base on the result of the validation.

Unfortunately, this piece of code is a part of a large implementation developed by someone else.  I just want to add the validation part without having to modify too much logic within the code.

Is there any way to put a condition on `ng-href`?  So that when **Finish** is clicked, the browser will only follow the URL if validation passes.  Otherwise, is there anyway to perform the same **GET** programmatically within the controller?  I've looked at using `$http.get()` and `$window.location.href`.  The former seem to be AJAX which does not redirect the browser to the name URL.  The latter, I don't know how to expand the `ctrl.model` into a proper **GET** string.

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestion would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!!

**Solution Used**

*HTML:*

```
<a data-ng-click="ctrl.createReport()">Finish</a>
```

*JS:*

```
if (validate()) {
    $location.path('/report/' + angular.toJson(self.model, false));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the ng-href all together. and use the $location service.

```
function createReport(){
    if(myForm.$valid){
        $location.path('/report'+model);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for the response.  I had tried that originally, I thought that would be the most straight forward and simple code.  However, $location service will not convert the "model" into a JSON string properly in the URL.  Here's what I get when I use your approach:  `http://localhost/TestApp/#/report/%5Bobject%20Object%5D`

Comment: Ok, I was able to get the proper json string by using the `angular.toJson()` function.  Works now, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize that `model` was an object.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, this piece of code is a part of a large implementation developed by someone else. I just want to add the validation part without having to modify too much logic within the code.

I have a hack for you. This directive eats the click if the expression returns false. So, the href is never followed by the browser. Also prevents the execution of ng-click.

**javascript**

```
module.directive('eatClickIf', ['$parse', '$rootScope',
  function($parse, $rootScope) {
    return {
      // this ensure eatClickIf be compiled before ngClick and ngHref
      priority: 100,
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function($element, attr) {
        var fn = $parse(attr.eatClickIf);
        return {
          pre: function link(scope, element) {
            var eventName = 'click';
            element.on(eventName, function(event) {
              var callback = function() {
                if (fn(scope, {$event: event})) {
                  // prevents ng-click to be executed
                  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                  // prevents href 
                  event.preventDefault();
                  return false;
                }
              };
              if ($rootScope.$$phase) {
                scope.$evalAsync(callback);
              } else {
                scope.$apply(callback);
              }
            });
          },
          post: function() {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**html**

```
<a ng-href="#/report/{{ctrl.model}}" 
   ng-click="ctrl.createReport()" 
   eat-click-if="!ctrl.modelIsValid()">Finish</a>
```

Comment: oneway, I found a more simple way for achieving what I needed.  But it's good to know that there is a way to intercept and prevent a click.  May come handy in another case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to remove the `ng-href` value and change path from js condition using `$location`

```
<a ng-href="" ng-click="ctrl.createReport()">Finish</a>
```

Inject `$location` sservice and do:

```
$location.path('/newValue')
```